# IIS stops logging all response headers when a certain response header is added

Tags: logging, iis, response-headers

I am looking to improve the IIS logging by including certain response headers. However i have found that adding a certain response header results in IIS not logging ANY of the response headers. However when i inspect the response itself the headers are all present.

I'm not sure if this is a character or length issue.

Here is the response header (as confirmed in a powershell request):

```
Header: RetryAttempts  
Value: MaxCom:3|MaxBE:3|Attempt:1|ComError:-2147164157|Attempt:2|ComError:-2147164157|Attempt:3|TotalAttempt:3|Success:True
```

If i enable this response header, it and all other fields become blank in the iis log file, represented by a "-".

Any idea what is causing this issue?

[Edit]
From some experimenting, i found eliminating the longer fields helped but not completely. I also had to shorten the name of the fields themselves although i haven't been able to find a clear correlation in the size limit.

with full names i would get no data logging, changing the fields to just an incrementing number i would get data. Ultimately i found a short enough name that met both requirements (meaningful + logging).

Would be good to know what the limit is on the field definitions themselves.

as a test i tried adding 20 more numeric fields that didn't map to a real response and that was fine so i'm at a loss as to what limit i was hitting since both the field name and content could be exceeded but some magic combination of the two could not.

Comment: What if you eliminate all `-` and `:` from the `Value` field? IIS is not bug free and custom logging is a relatively new piece of code, so anything can happen.

Comment: will give that a try, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Justin Has your problem been solved?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to the characters, but it does seem to have problems with long field names. Using field names of < 5 chars seems to work reliably